# ESP-8266 stopped working due to possibly faulty perfboard layout

Tags: esp8266, softwareserial

I have been following [this tutorial](http://www.deviceplus.com/how-tos/arduino-guide/esp8266-setup-tutorial-using-arduino/) to set up my ESP8266. I have also recreated on a perfboard the circuit provided in the tutorial, and I intend to use this perfboard circuit in my project.

The problem arises when I plug my ESP into the perfboard and try to talk to it through the serial monitor. When using a baud rate of 115200, the ESP responds to commands but in a garbled format. Also, the blue LED stays on after powerup for increasingly long periods of time. Now the blue LED is always on and the ESP no longer responds to any commands, except when reset and asked for the startup firmware info. I suspect that the ESP is now broken but am not sure how to check.

Also note that the ESP was working fine on a breadboard at 9600 baud, prior to the blue LED incident. Now it won't work with the breadboard either.

All commands were sent with newline and carriage return.

Is the ESP8266 broken? Could there be something wrong with my perfboard circuit? The circuit is rather dense and contains wiring for several other components in addition to the ESP-8266.

Comment: most ESP8266's default baud rate is the non standard `74880` (which is 115200 * 26 / 40)

Comment: @JaromandaX when serial monitor is set to 74880 baud the "boot message" shows up when resetting the board. However I'm unable to get a response from any commands sent to the board, at any baud rate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out the real culprit was the `AT+IPR=9600` command bricking the board. The board was "fixed" by obtaining the [firmware](https://github.com/espressif/ESP8266_NONOS_SDK) and flashing it to the board using `esptool.py`. Download the repo's source code, navigate to the directory `bin/at/`, and see the file `README.md` to see which addresses to flash the different parts to.